# Is there a way to get the value of nested dict in Immutabledict sent via request of werkzeug(flask)?

Tags: python, request, flask, python-requests, werkzeug

I asked question in past, but still facing the problem.
    address_dict = {'address': {'US': 'San Francisco', 'US': 'New York', 'UK': 'London'}}

When above parameters was sent via requests, how can I get values in address key using request.form on Flask?

```
import requests
url =  'http://example.com'
params = {"address": {"US": "San Francisco", "UK": "London", "CH": "Shanghai"}}
requests.post(url, data=params)
```

Then I got this in context of flask.request.

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('address', u'US'), ('address', 'US'), ('address', 'UK')])
```

How can I get the value in each key of addresses?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

You're sending complex nested data structure as HTML form, it won't work like you expect.  Encode it as JSON:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'http://example.com/'
payload = {"address": {"US": "San Francisco", "UK": "London", "CH": "Shanghai"}}
data = json.dumps(payload)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

In you Flask app it would be accesible via `request.json` (already decoded).

Comment: Thanks, I see. In request.form, can I get the nested value? Because our module about API send data via dictionary(request.form).

Comment: If it's API, why not forget forms at all and use JSON? It's more convenient. In case of my example, in your Flask app from 'request.json` you would get the same dictionary you have sent.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I'm thinking about the case the request sent via curl or other http request client. I'd like to integrate just one solution(request.form or request.json)